# Error Message: Cannot call constructor Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php

Tags: php

```
public function __construct(&$params)
{
    parent::__construct($params);

    if (isset($this->_config['save_path']))
    {
        $this->_config['save_path'] = rtrim($this->_config['save_path'], '/\\');
        ini_set('session.save_path', $this->_config['save_path']);
    }
    else
    {
        log_message('debug', 'Session: "sess_save_path" is empty; using "session.save_path" value from php.ini.');
        $this->_config['save_path'] = rtrim(ini_get('session.save_path'), '/\\');
    }

    $this->_sid_regexp = $this->_config['_sid_regexp'];

    isset(self::$func_overload) OR self::$func_overload = (extension_loaded('mbstring') && ini_get('mbstring.func_overload'));
}
```

> An uncaught Exception was encountered Type: Error Message: Cannot call constructor Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\system\libraries\Session\drivers\Session_files_driver.php Line Number: 22 Backtrace: File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\application\controllers\admin\Login.php Line: 9 Function: __construct File: C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\index.php Line: 162 Function: require_once